# Shouldn't Pandas.cut() return a dtype object column?

Tags: python, pandas

The following piece of code, where the following two functions are being used by the `TheColumnTransformer` from `sklearn`:

```
def age_transformer(X):
    X_copy = X.copy()
    median_age_by_class = X_copy.groupby('Pclass')['Age'].median().reset_index()
    median_age_by_class.columns = ['Pclass', 'median_age']
    for index, row in median_age_by_class.iterrows():
        class_value = row['Pclass']
        median_age = row['median_age']
        X_copy.loc[X_copy['Pclass'] == class_value, 'Age'] = X_copy.loc[X_copy['Pclass'] == class_value, 'Age'].fillna(median_age)
    bins = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100]
    X_copy['age_interval'] = pd.cut(X_copy['Age'], bins=bins)
    return X_copy

def age_processor():
    return make_pipeline(
        FunctionTransformer(age_transformer, feature_names_out=interval_name),
    )
```

is returning:

```
df['age_processing__interval'].value_counts()

age_processing__interval
(20, 30]     377
(30, 40]     185
(10, 20]     115
(40, 50]      86
(0, 10]       64
(50, 60]      42
(60, 70]      17
(70, 100]      5
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

and

```
df.info()
 1   age_processing__interval  891 non-null    interval[int64, right]
```

I don't understand why the dtype is `int64`. Shoudn't it be a dtype `object` by default? What is the problem here?

Comment: Is `age_processing__interval` supposed to be `age_interval`?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html): "The values stored within are whatever the type in the sequence is." Since the labels are integers, the dtype of the result is int64.

Comment: you are right, I changed the labels with string names and it worked. I am tired because I am working with for some hours now haha but it is ok. I thought the cut would return categories by default. Thanks for the time.